# How to find if all animations have completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a jquery login box and I want to show one form, only if all other animations are complete.

I understand I can do multiple `.is(':animated')` checks, but I was wondering, is there a way to select all animated objects and the check if I have selected exactly zero elements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if ($(":animated").length === 0) {
   // do something

}
```

As per Jasper's comment, and what it says in the [`:animated` selector doco](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/), you can improve performance by selecting a container element or otherwise narrowing down the field before using `:animated`. E.g.,

```
if ($("#container").find(":animated").length === 0) {

// OR

if ($(".someClass").filter(":animated").length === 0) {
```

Comment: If you know a container that the animated elements will be descendants of, it's probably a good idea to start your selection with that container so not every node in the DOM has to be traversed.

Comment: Thanks @Jasper, yes, I was just wondering whether to say something about that. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Wouldn't this just find elements that are in the process of being animated? Wouldn't you want to check the fx queue to see if there are elements that are yet to be animated?

Comment: @j08691 If there is an FX queue then wouldn't there always be something animating? Or if you set a delay for the animation is that not considered `:animated` while in the delay?

Comment: @Jasper - Right, I'm thinking a delay, or other situation where the queue is populated but not active. I suppose something like this would catch that: `$("*").each(function(){ console.log( $(this).queue("fx").length);});​` for all elements, or you could substitute a specific element over the wildcard.

Comment: `.delay()` is an animation. I haven't tested it, but I'm sure `:animated` will pick those up. I'm not sure how the fx queue could be populated but not active?